# How to place two img next to each other with text below responsive

Tags: html, css, image

I'm making my second test HTML file from PSD file.

In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUiP9.jpg) picture you may see my issue.

Could you please guide me how to sit two images next to each other which have text below?

Also I want it be responsive.

For example in large screens, the two images sit next each other. In small screens each image in one separate line.

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first have the image and text in a box like this:

```
<div class="contentBox">
    <img>
    <h3>some title</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

then float those boxes.

```
.contentBox{
    float:left;
}
```

I made a quick snippet to show you how you could use it:

```css
#boxes{
text-align:center;
}
.contentBox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

.contentBox img {
  width: 100%;
}

.contentBox h3 {
  margin: 5px;
}

.contentBox p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div class="contentBox">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x250">
    <h3>some title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis mauris sem, in elementum tortor eleifend vel.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="contentBox">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x250">
    <h3>some title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis mauris sem, in elementum tortor eleifend vel.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works, but your example at top says use .contentBox {float:left;} which you dont